# Histogram Factor Ordering

Tags: r

I'm having problems ordering my factors of my Histogram.
My data is something like this:

```
ID  onderlaag
1  strooisel
2  geen
3  strooisel
4  kniklaag
5  gras
6  geen
.
.
```

I've made my histogram using the barplot() function:

> barplot(table(onderlaag),ylim=c(0,250))

The order of the histogram bars here are alphabetically but I would like to have them ordered more in the order of: strooisel - geen - gras - kniklaag.

I have used the factor function but my barplot has no bars anymore after I've done this

> onderlaag2=factor(onderlaag,levels=c("Strooisel","Geen","Gras","Kniklaag"))

How can I do this?

Comment: If you want a histogram why aren't you using `hist()`?

Comment: This really isn't a histogram, and it would violate the expectations of the 'hist' function.  It's just an ordered frequency plot and does not have a discrete, continuous set of x-values.  The 'barplot' and 'table' functions are just one way of building this plot (I would recommend doing an aggregate function first), but I think that's a bit beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

please provide example data next time with `dput`

```
# construct an example data frame similar in structure to the question
x <- data.frame( ID = 1:4 , ord = c( 'b' , 'a' , 'b' , 'c' ) )

# look at the table of x, notice it's alphabetical
table( x )

# re-order the `ord` factor levels
levels( x$ord ) <- c( 'b' , 'a' , 'c' )

# look at x
x

# look at the table of x, notice `b` now comes first
table( x )

# print the results, even though it's not a histogram  ;)
barplot( table(x) , ylim = c( 0 , 5 ) )
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to create as "ordered". All you should need to do is specify the levels vector for the factor function in the desired order. Furthermore the data.frame call created x$ord as a factor to begin with, so you are not converting to a factor, you are re-leveling an existing factor. Could have been done with: `levels(x$ord) <- c( 'b' , 'a' , 'c' )`

Comment: agreed.. you only need `x$ord <- factor( x$ord , levels = c( 'b' , 'a' , 'c' ) , ordered = TRUE )` if `ord` is a character column

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking for is just a way of ordering the inputs, and this we can do rather easily as part of your 'barplot' function like so:

```
barplot(table(onderlaag)[,c(4,1,2,3)], ylim=c(0,250))
```

The 'table' function automatically sorts your columns for you, but you can manually specify the order afterwards.  The syntax of it works like this:

```
table(your_data)[rows_to_select, columns_to_select]
```

Where `your_data` is the data being made into a table, `rows_to_select` is a list of filters to be applied to the rows, and `columns_to_select` is a list of filters to be applied to the columns.  By not specifying `rows_to_select`, we are selecting all rows, and by specifying `columns_to_select` as `c(4,1,2,3)`, we are selecting all four columns but in a specific order.